# how to concatenate multiple cells but return value only from cell having data

Tags: if-statement, concatenation

Need answer to below please....

I have 4 different cells in a row and out of those 4 cells only one cell has text and the rest of cells have 0 in it, i want to concatenate/combine those 4 cells(not in a consecutive range) and return only value from the cell which has text and not zero

Comment: Please, start with providing some code.

Comment: Hi...thanks for replying....actually...i just need a simple formula in excel...i don't want VBA coding

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try the following if the range you're working with is is from `A1:D1`

```
=IF(A1:D1<>0, CELL("contents",A1:D1),"")
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: thanks for the reply, i want to apply the formulas in rows, so i tried below, =IF(I2:K2<>0, CELL("contents",I2:K2),"")  but it gives me error #Value

Comment: Hmm. I just tried this =IF(A1:D1<>0, CELL("contents",A1:D1),"") and it worked fine. Sorry I misunderstood your question I will edit accordingly

Comment: @simmy be sure to mark as correct. I think you should post your question on SO

Comment: Hi sorry but somehow this code is not working for me from A2:D2 i have "HI" in B2 and "0" in other cells but its not returning me HI in the E2 its agin returning #value error

Comment: hmm....that could be problem....because i wanted to have the result on the same row cell...but many thanks for helping out!!!! much appreciated!!!